# git exclude individual branches from fetch

Tags: git, branch

My repository 'origin' has several branches that I do not want see in git log --all. How can I exclude individual remote branches from my local repository?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to solve my problem:

```
git config --add remote.origin.fetch ^refs/heads/remove-branch-I-want-to-ignore
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `--not --remotes=`, and then list branches which you'd like to exclude.
For example:
`git log --all --not --remotes=origin/master, origin/HEAD`
will list commits just for `origin/develop`, without `master` branch.

Comment: That looks good but will requires a lot of writing. Is there a way to always exclude a branch?

Comment: You could create `alias` for that command. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases